# Is there a better way to implement a generalized "changing" idiom for Python?

Tags: python, idioms

The phrase "repeat until the value stops changing" is common in algorithms and the implementation in real programming languages has always felt a bit clumsy. I've been using the following generalized function to clean up my algorithms where clarity trumps efficiency:

```py
def changing(o):
    ret = getattr(changing, 'last_value_', None) != o
    changing.last_value_ = copy.deepcopy(o)
    return ret
```

used in the following way:

```py
first = collections.defaultdict(set)
while changing(first):
    for left, right in GRAMMAR:
        right = right[0]
        if right in T:
            first[left].add(right)
        else:
            first[left] = first[left] | first[right]
```

Clearly this is grossly inefficient and doesn't work if the first value is `None` and could be accomplished less brute-force if we knew the data structure ahead of time and how it changed.

But is there a better way in Python to accomplish the "this value is clearly different from this other value"?

Comment: I'm not aware of such idiom. I'm afraid the mentioned ineficiency of a generalized solution speaks against the existence of such idiom.

Comment: Crack open an algorithms text book and you are bound to find scores of algorithms that say something to the affect of "repeat such-and-such until the result no longer changes". Another term used is "convergence to the solution". Normally it's implemented with a flag that is reset on each iteration and then tripped inside a branch that causes a change. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser#Creating_new_item_sets for an example of this idiom.

Comment: Sure there is plenty of cases where it is used, I just mean there is no Python idiom for it AFAIK. The two main approaches (before/after comparison and is_modified flag) are quite different code.